# Complex Gridview Edit

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that displays data in a crosstab format.  The hours for each day are displayed.   Each day is actually a separate row in the underlying table, so a row in the grid represents seven underlying tables.

```
WeekEnding(sat)  Project  Category   Sun  Mon  Tues  Wed  Thur  Fri  Sat

8/14/2010        Proj1    testing         1    2     2    3     2
```

I want to write custom code to update each day.  I have to caclulate the date based on weekending date and day ( ex fri date == Weekending - 1 day) and make 7 different update statements - one for each day in the row.

Where can I do this?   Would I use the Gridview ItemUpdating event(edit: I meant RowUpdating event)?

======================

I need to add code when they click the "Update" button but not sure what event that is.

Currently when they click edit i have a textbox that appears for each days hours

Comment: What do you mean by "writing custom code to update each day"?  What sort of update are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the user to be able to change the hours under each day.  Even though sun-sat is diplayed in one row in the grid it is not one row in the database.  they are seven different rows and each will need to be updated in edit mode.

Comment: `RowEditing` happens when you click the `edit` button, and `RowUpdating` happens when you click the `update` button. Because it sounds like you have multiple statements that occur when an update happens, you will need to write your own custom code in the codebehind, like you suggested (You can't use the asp:gridviewadapter for this updating).

Answer (score 0):

Use the RowDataBound since you aleady have all the information you need to do this, inside this event you can get the complete object information that is bound and use the findControl to update the columns